# What attacks can be performed on victim's machine after socket connection?

Tags: python, security, client-side-attacks

I have an assignment where i need to implement three attacks after socket connection with python. I already did socket connection and implemented ransomware and key logger. I need one more attack implementation. Can anyone suggest me one attack that i can perform on the client's/ victim's side besides these two?

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas that I have right now are:

- If you have root access, you can basically have fun with some files and change their permissions. Maybe create a new user to access those files only.
- You can try making a virus that could for instance create multiple processes of itself and slow down the victim's machine.
- You could also create a script that scans for files in a certain directory (ex: Downloads) and send them to your machine.
- You could try to modify some browser settings (called browser hijacking).

I might add more ideas later. Good luck